# ActionScript 3 - Developing for Touch Screen in Windows 7 and 8

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, touch

I will be developing for a Windows powered touch screen without mouse or keyboard, using Flash CS6 or Flash CC.

I understand that my first option is to use the usual mouse events, where tapping is equivalent to clicking. Is this correct? If so, in this case does it matter if I target the Flash player and publish as an .EXE win projector file, or instead target Air 3.4 for Desktop?

If gestures do becomes necessary, what should I target and how should I publish? Also, in the absence of the touch-screen during development, can I test on a tablet instead using Air? Is it roughly equivalent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, click events are mapped to touch events. I don't really see any problem with publishing it as a projector, however I am not sure I see why you would do it, the capabilities of Air are much better than those of Flash player.

You can use gestures on whatever that supports the API, that should be FP 10.3+ & Air 2.6+ if I see correctly. However that API sucks big time, there is other libraries available which are better (e.g. Gestouch). You can also test it on mobile, of course, but you will have to change your project to an Android/iOS mobile project. Shouldn't be a big problem tho.

Answer (score 0):

Flash CC can't export EXE, just saying.